# Delete Multiple Rows From WPF Datagrid using Checkbox and Delete button

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that contains a checkbox. I would like to delete all the rows from the DataGrid where the checkbox is checked by clicking on a delete button. The XAML for my datagrid is shown below.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="orders" Grid.Row="4" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Select" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" ></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I would like to write code for click button to delete all the rows where the checkbox is checked like so.

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Delete logic here

    }
```

How do I achieve this?
NB: I'm using EntityFramework and not ADO. the datagrid is bound to an observable collection of type Order like `ObservableCollection<Order>`

Comment: What is the current behavior based on what you have tried as apposed to what is the expected behavior. If the check box is bound properly then it is just a matter of getting the `SelectedItems` and removing them from the collection.

Comment: Maybe a code snippet can help. How do I get the rows that are checked.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure the `DataGrid` allows multi-selection via the [SelectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
SelectionMode="Extended"
```

Then on button click get the selected items from the grid based on the `IsSelected` binding in the view

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    //get selected items
    if (orders.SelectedItems != null && orders.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
        var toRemove = orders.SelectedItems.Cast<Order>().ToList();
        //Delete logic here
        //...remove items from EF and save

        //Once confirmed remove from items source
        var items = orders.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Order>;
        if (items != null) {
            foreach (var order in toRemove) {
                items.Remove(order);       
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Write code behind like this....
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Great> p = new List<Great>();
            p.Add(new Great() { Name = "Good" });
            p.Add(new Great() { Name = "Bad" });
            p.Add(new Great() { Name = "Ugly" });
            orders.ItemsSource = p;

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Great> SelectedOrders = new List<Great>();
            for (int i = 0; i < orders.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                SelectedOrders.Add((Great)orders.SelectedItems[i]);
            }
            var kk = orders.ItemsSource as List<Great>;
            foreach (var item in SelectedOrders)
            {
                kk.Remove(item);
            }
            orders.Items.Refresh();
        }

       public class Great
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `Clear()` method on the `ObservableCollection<Order>`:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sourceCollection = orders.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Order>;
    if (orders != null)
        orders.Clear();
}
```